# Whats the max character length of android XML id's?

Tags: android, xml, android-widget

Whats's the max length of an Android XML widget id.

Like of a `TextView`:

```xml
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/whatIsTheMaxLength"/>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479076/what-is-the-typical-maximum-length-of-values-of-the-xml-xsd-id-idref-types

Comment: Why do you set the id with a String? Shouldn't it be like `"@+id/some_id"` instead?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, its translated to an int during the compile stage.  If there is a max size, its the max size of a Java identifier which is 64K bytes